# Vertical and Horizontal Tables

Tags: sql

Can anyone tell me what's the performance gain when using a vertical table for searching?  What's faster, a vertical or an horizontal table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By "vertical" table, do you mean the [EAV model](http://tonyandrews.blogspot.com/2004/10/otlt-and-eav-two-big-design-mistakes.html)?  If so, it is generally **slower** to search than a normal "horizontal" table.  Its usual justification is not performance, but flexibility at the cost of performance and probably data integrity too.

Answer (score 3):

A good article

[Using Vertical and Horizontal Table Structures in Oracle](http://www.developer.com/db/article.php/3736011/Using-Vertical-and-Horizontal-Table-Structures-in-Oracle.htm)